# Get Gridview Cell Value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got a gridview with a checkbox column, which I'm able to determine whether a row is checked. My problem is that I can't get the cell value. I'm using javascript. I'm using JS since I have to make an ajax call once I get the cell value.  Thx in advance.  Here's my code:

```
    function newData(mode) {

        if (mode == 'edit') {
            var valid = false; 
            var gv = document.getElementById("myGridview"); 

            for (var i = 0; i < gv.all.length; i++) { 
                var node = gv.all[i]; 
                if (node != null && node.type == "checkbox" && node.checked) { 
                    valid = true; 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
            if (!valid) { 
                alert("Invalid. Please select a checkbox to continue."); 
            } 

            return valid; 
        }
```

Comment: To clarify: do you currently have a row of checkbox elements, are able to find the checkbox you want to get a value from, but do not know how to tell whether said checkbox has been checked or not?

Comment: I do know when the checkbox has been checked.  I can get to the line where it says:   valid=true;     that said, it's finding the first row where it finds a box checked.   The first column on the grid is where I got the checkbock, which I want it work as a button. I need to have this done at the client side, no postback. Thx

Comment: Please share you aspx code for the gridview. This can be handled far better by adding a class to the checkbox and using jQuery to find it.

Comment: jQuery might be overkill, but yeah I think I might need a bit more code detail before being able to add anything useful - I'm still not quite clear what the relationship between the checked box and the value you're trying to retrieve; I think I'd need to see the html.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your GridView's ID will change when rendered as HTML, so your document.getElementById("myGridview") should change to document.getElementById(myGridview.ClientID) which would return correct HTML table name.

Try debugging the javascript using Firebug or IE developer tool.

Happy coding!!!